# Можно ли записать DataFrame в Excel поверх существующего файла?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

То есть у меня уже есть созданный файл с именем report.xlsx, в котором есть два листа.

Можно ли записать в третий лист свой DataFrame?

Просто когда я использую:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx') as writer:
    itog_bdp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='третий',index=False)
```

То файл пересоздаётся и данные с него стираются.

Answer (score 1):

Режим открытия устанавливать нужно. При этом, учитывая то, что при записи первого листа (когда файл ещё не создан) нужно указать режим "w", а после этого дописывать с режимом "a".

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    itog_bdp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='первый',index=False)

with pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    itog_bdp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='третий',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавите параметр `mode='a'` в конструктор `ExcelWriter`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
```

потому что стандартным значением этого параметра является `'w'`, что значит *переписать файл*.

Значение `'a'` значит *добавить*.

---

Когда бы это не сработало, добавите параметр `engine='openpyxl'`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx', mode='a', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
```

(Спасибо [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) - см. его комментарий).

Comment: попробовал данное решение с Pandas v.0.25.3 - получаю `"ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!"` - у вас нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо вам. B Pandas v.0.25.3 надо добавить параметр engine='openpyxl' т. к. стандартным в этой версии является xlsxwriter не позволяющий режим append.